# NodeJS bulk remove mongodb documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-query

I have a collection with some bad data. I would like to bulk delete this data based on some query. This is easy in the mongo shell as `db.collection.remove()` allows you to specify the `justOne` option. Is there some way to do this in the node.js driver? `findAndRemove` seems to only delete 1 document and has no option to make it bulk?

```
db.collection(collection_name, function(err, collection){
  collection.findAndRemove({type: 'LUXURY'}, function(err, result){
    // result is only a single document
    console.log(result._id.toString());
  });
});
```

I know an alternative to this is to `find()` all documents that satisfy my query and manually create a BulkOp using `initializeUnorderedBulkOp` and populate it by iterating over the results of my find, but I feel there should be an easier way.

Comment: Have you looked at mongoose yet? Its super full featured and would have the delete you are looking for. I've used this on several sites and its awesome. http://mongoosejs.com/

Comment: I'd heard of it, but didn't think to give it a try. I will look into it. Do you recommend migrating all of my code over to use mongoose or is it common practice to interweave the mongo driver with mongoose?

Comment: Tested code is gold. I wouldn't migrate it all over if its working. I would start to introduce it into new functionality and migrate over as it makes sense but not as some rule, especially since the logic/syntax is so similar. I really love Mongoose, can't say enough good about it and am using it on several projects.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use [remove](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#remove) function directly?

Comment: I was certain I'd looked for that first, but looking again, it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using node-mongo-native driver, I can't see any reason why you don't use the [remove](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#remove) directly.

```
db.collection(collection_name, function(err, collection){
  collection.remove({type: 'LUXURY'}, function(err, result){
    // your code here.
  });
});
```